# Java applet needed for rich text editing

Tags: java

I need Java to get fonts, bold, underline etc when using timewarner email.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.  Where to I get and how do I install Java to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

## Installing JRE

1. Download JRE from Oracle's JRE Downloads pages and extract it to any directory. (For me, its /home/*user*/installs/jre)
2. Now run `find /home/user/installs/jre -name "libnpjp2.so"`
3. **Copy the location** and continue with the following options.

## For Mozilla Firefox

1. You will need to create a symbolic link of libnpjp2.so file under mozilla's plugin directory.

> ```
> cd ~/.mozilla
> mkdir -p plugins
> cd plugins
> ln -s <COPIED_TEXT> ./
> ```

2. Now open firefox and visit `https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp` to check the successful installation of Java plugin

## For Chrome

As of Chrome version 45, Java Applets cannot be run on Chrome.

## References

[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Guide/Plug-in_Basics#How_Gecko_Finds_Plug-ins

[3] https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/npapi_plugin_perspectives_and_the

[4] https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml